# Make a service monitor and restart process

Tags: c#, service

i'm making an app that needs to be up and running at all times. (24/7)
I'm  not very expirienced with services, but I read on the internet that services can be made uncolasble by setting their "onclose" property to false.

I have got the service monitoring my app, and the service can't be closed directly from the task manager services window... but, when I click "go to process" task manager leads me to the process the service spawned. From there I can close the process and instantly close the service.
Since I don't have much expirience with services i'm wondering, is this behavior normal? If not, how to make the service unstopable?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I'm not sure that such a way exists. Definitely if I install software on my machine I don't want it to restart itself if I decide to kill it.

Comment: If you need an app to be running at all times why not just make it a service? Then it can run even when nobody is logged in. Is there some reason you need it to be a forms/window application?

Comment: @Tony I thought OP had made a service but didn't want it killed?

Comment: I'm doing a software for a company that makes some graphics stuff in photoshop, and the owner wants to track down EXACT time employees spend in which app. Preety much everything i did works except that. Some expirienced users tried to mess with the app a couple of times and closed it. It's not mine to question anything, i'm just here to try to make the app "unclosable"... So any ideas are welcome!
btw: thanks in advance!

Comment: @Martin & Tony, yeah, it's already a service, but it can be "killed" even if I set the OnClose property to false.

Comment: Well in a domain environment you should be able to prevent them gaining access to task manager I think.

Comment: @Martin: I just thought I'd check because the way I read this: 'I have got the service monitoring my app' was there is an application (a term I usually interpret to mean something with a GUI) monitored by a service.

Comment: As @Martin said, be careful about having an unkillable process (even one an employer wants to run) as it just starts an "arms race": http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need something like [Slife Teams](http://www.slifeteams.com/) and then use Windows security to prevent them killing the client app.

**Edit**
If you are using Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 maybe you can use [AppLocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791823(WS.10).aspx)?

**Edit 2**
Getting back to answering the original question, one way would be to create your monitoring app so that there are two processes running, both monitoring, that know about each other.

Run the two processes, each with an open handle to the other process.  When one process is detected as being killed the other process immediately restarts it, and vice-versa.

You will need to handle the normal system shutdown messages.

Or... have a read of this article: [Process Invincibility](http://www.rootkit.com/newsread.php?newsid=139)

Comment: A rootkit?  You gotta be kidding.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use it but I thought I'd include it in my answer for completeness. :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the anwser, but rootkits are not an option :)

Comment: I dind't really expect you to go for that part of the answer :) 
Personally, I'd use the two processes "supporting" each other, even if only one of them is doing the actual monitoring.

Comment: yeah, that was my second option.. did that today and it works... it looks a bit ugly heaving two unnecessary processes in the task manager, but it does the trick...